# Turn off Like button - Soundcloud Widget Parameter

Tags: button, soundcloud, social-media-like

I'm trying to turn off Like button, but parameter "liking" does not work and still shows Like button (others like: show art, comments are ok)

My iframe:

```
<iframe width="100%"  height="450" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2F<?php echo $id; ?>&show_artwork=true&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false></iframe>
```

The playlist is private.

```
$id = "playlists%2F1234567%3Fsecret_token…"
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the same issue. See here with a different playlist: http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1815863&show_artwork=true&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false

Comment: thank you Nick, can you turn off "share" future and "get the app" button?
maybe there is a problem (I do not have them enabled)

Comment: still can't see any problems (http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1815863&show_artwork=true&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false&sharing=false&buying=false). The only other thing I could think of is that there's some issue with private playlists. Could you try with a non-private playlist and see if you can recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

it works when you add at the end "&sharing=false&buying=false"
it does not work when "liking=false" is at the end of iframe

Comment: I'm still not seeing that myself: `http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1815863&show_artwork=true&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false` http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1815863&show_artwork=true&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false

Comment: Thanks Nick for helping me, your example proved that turning off the buttons is possible :)
Do not know why it does not work, but workaround works.

Comment: could you send me a link to one which doesn't work even with `liking=false` at the end?

Comment: Hi can't reproduce the issue, it looks like it has something to do with the web browser caching

Comment: hey I referred to this issue and I have the same problem. How do I hide the like button? The link is http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F63422331&amp;&show_artwork=false&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false&sharing=false&buying=false&show_bpm=false;color=ff7700

Comment: This one works for me
"&show_artwork=true&liking=false&buying=false&sharing=false&show_comments=false&show_playcount=false&show_user=false"
but it does not with your track, have no idea why